# How to prevent tzdata updates on CentOS resetting /etc/localtime

Tags: centos, yum, timezone

I am using a local timezone (non-UTC) on my server. Whenever I update the tzdata via yum, the system resets /etc/localtime to the default file and I am back on UTC.

While #date still shows the proper timezone, CRON and other services switch to UTC.

How can I prevent that?

Comment: that's very unlikely because the tzdata rpm package does not own the `/etc/localtime` file and contains no post-install script fiddling with it. (https://git.centos.org/blob/!!rpms!tzdata.git/306e242c40d39f415a78aa5d9fadf3ef44ec32d3/SPECS!tzdata.spec)

Comment: @guido But, try `$ rpm -q --triggeredby tzdata`, and you'll see the glibc-common package has a script triggered by tzdata update. Specifically, it runs `/usr/sbin/tzdata-update`. (This is on CentOS 6 and earlier; things are different with systemd.)

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l /etc/localtime` and `cat /etc/sysconfic/clock`?

Answer (score 3):

My CentOS knowledge is a bit out of date, but you may need to also specify the timezone in `/etc/sysconfig/clock`.

As a last-ditch effort, of course, you could:

```
chattr +i /etc/localtime  # immutable
```

It is surprising that `tzdata` munges `/etc/localtime` though. Have you made it a symlink to `/usr/share/zoneinfo/...`? Are you perhaps updating `glibc` at the same time as `tzdata`? (since the `glibc` package owns `/etc/localtime`)

Comment: I use `sudo ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Amsterdam /etc/localtime` to update the time. After a tzdata update, the time is reset to UTC. After changing the clock to `Europe/Amsterdam`, this doesn't happen anymore. Maybe this is not the correct way to set localtime, but your answer seems to fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

All RH based system before version 7 the correct way was to set in `/etc/sysconfig/clock` and then run `tzdata-update`. The `tzdata` rpm runs this so that's why it resets it.

In version 7 we have `timedatectl...`

Comment: There is no time limit, you can post new answers any time. But they should be good quality and significantly different as the already existing ones.